# ValueError:setting an array element with a sequence for SVM.Fit model

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I have used the sklearn built-in function `classifier.fit(X_svm_train,Y_train)` for doing binary classification.

My `X_svm_train` and `Y_train` dimensions are the same, but I am confused why I am getting this error and how to rectify it:

```
X_svm_train:(200, 7290)
Y_train=200
```

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
classifier=SVC(gamma=0.01,C=10,kernel='poly')
classifier.fit(X_svm_train,Y_train)
```

```
c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
       packages\sklearn\svm\base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
       144         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
       145                          order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
    --> 146                          accept_large_sparse=False)
       147         y = self._validate_targets(y)
       148 

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, 
accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, 
allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, 
 y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
         717                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
         718                     warn_on_dtype=warn_on_dtype,
     --> 719                     estimator=estimator)
         720     if multi_output:
         721         y = check_array(y, 'csr', force_all_finite=True, 
  ensure_2d=False,

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, 
accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, 
allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, 
estimator)
    494             try:
    495                 warnings.simplefilter('error', ComplexWarning)
--> 496                 array = np.asarray(array, dtype=dtype, 
  order=order)
    497             except ComplexWarning:
    498                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\core\numeric.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
    536 
    537     """
--> 538     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    539 
    540 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 1):

From the Stacktrace , This is caused by improper shape of the `Y_train` or `X_train` , make sure that your `Y_train` is of Shape (`Num_rows , 1)`

Also , Make sure `X_train` has the shape `(Num_rows , num_features)`

A `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence` is usually caused by  trying to cram a sequence of numbers into a single number slot.

eg ->

```
import numpy

numpy.array([1,2,3])               #good

numpy.array([1, (2,3)])            #Fail, can't convert a tuple into a numpy 
                                   #array element
```